# React Router, maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Getting some weird errors when trying to set up react routing

This is my main index.js file

```
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render(){
    return (
       <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path={'/'} component={App}>
          <Route path={'/quizzes'} component={Quiz}> </Route>
        </Route>
       </Router>
      )
  };
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
    document.getElementById('content'));
```

I get the error saying `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

no idea why

Comment: <Route path={'/'} component={App}> isnt that recursion?

Comment: but if I remove it I get `[react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes`

Comment: it's ok I solved it now. set a different location to /

Answer (score 3):

You are rendering your App which you have rendering the router.  Then the router renders App  which is an infinite loop.  I think you meant to do something more like this...

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
       {this.props.children}
      </div>
      )
  };
};

ReactDOM.render(
       <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path={'/'} component={App}>
          <Route path={'/quizzes'} component={Quiz}> </Route>
        </Route>
       </Router>,
    document.getElementById('content'));
```

Now, instead of rendering App which renders a router, which renders the app, you're just rendering the router at the start, then because you'll likely test the default route... "/" it will render the app and any child components based on your route.

See: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-route